# Seeking elements in nested lists

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to make a function that is able to find a element in a nested list.
That is what if got so far:

```
    def in_list(ele, lst, place):
        if ele == lst[place]:
            return True
        else:
            for i in range(len(lst)):
                in_list(ele, lst[i], place)
```

This is what i input:

```
    a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
    if in_list(2,a,1)==True:
        print("True")
```

the variable "place" is the place in the list where the element should be found...
Now somehow it doesn't understand this line `if ele == lst[place]`
this is the error message: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the lists too? And your first call to the method in_list with the arguments you are using?

Comment: What arguments are you passing in when you call the function?

Comment: At some level of the recursion, `lst[i]` will be a number (i.e. when you reach the most-nested list). On that call, `lst[place]` will raise the error you get because it's not a list anymore.

Comment: `ele` is a integer such as `place` is.

Comment: should your last example print True? what if `a = [[3,4],[1,2]]`, should it print True then too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in the last line

```
def in_list(ele, lst, place):
    if ele == lst[place]:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            in_list(ele, lst[i], place)
```

`lst[i]` is an integer (assuming `lst` is a list of integers), which is why you get your error.

The other issue is that you're not returning anything from the `else` branch.

Something like this might work better in case of arbitrary, but uniform, nesting:

```
def recursive_contains(item, lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return False
    elif isinstance(lst[0], collections.Iterable):
        return any(recursive_contains(item, sublist) for sublist in lst)
    else:
        return item in lst
```

for arbitrary non-uniform nesting, perhaps something like this:

```
def recursive_contains(item, lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, collections.Iterable):
        return item == lst
    for val in lst:
        if item == val:
            return True
        elif isinstance(val, collections.Iterable):
            if recursive_contains(item, val):
                return True
    return False
```

of course if you only have 2 levels (all elements of lst are lists of int), you could simply say:

```
if ele in sum(lst, []):
    ...
```

which uses `sum` to flatten the list first.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers well define the mistake in your code.
Just to reiterate that you were assuming each element in the list as a nested list and subscripting it like - **elem[place]**.

You can't subscript a primitive type such as integer and hence the error.
Refer the below code to handle nesting.

Note - You Don't require the 3rd parameter of place, more appropriately you wouldn't the place if you are searching.*

```
def fetch(data, l):
for element in l:
    if type(element) == list:
        if fetch(data, element):
            return True
    else:
        if element == data:
            return True
return False
```

On further thought you are looking for an element that should be only at **"place"** index of any of the nested lists.
Refer to the snippet below for that-

```
def fetch(data, l,place):
if data == l[place]:
    return True
else:
    for element in l:
        if type(element) == list and fetch(data,element,place):
            return True
return False
```

*Note- Only call fetch again if the element is a list.*

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]


def inlist(e, l, p):
    for lists in range(len(l)):
        print("array:", l[lists])
        print("Looking for", e)
        print("In position", p)
        print(l[lists][p])
        if l[lists][p] == e:
            print(True, ": The element ", e, " is in the list n.", lists, " at the place ", p)
            return True


inlist(2, a, 1)
```

> Output
>
> ```
> array: [1, 2]
> Looking for 2
> In position 1
> 2
> True : The element  2  is in the list n. 0  at the place  1
> ```